# Copying test report generated by Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to copy a test run report generated by maven to a different location on the same machine. I have written the code to copy the report in the teardown method but currently the problem is that the report is generated by maven at the end of the test run hence the tear down method is not able to find the report. Please let me know where exactly the code for copying the report should be written

Comment: I dont understand where and how you are calling code from maven. But i would suggest to write a maven plugin to do the job for you. Plus, writing a maven plugin is easier than it sounds. http://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the Surefire Report plugin to generate the report in a different place:

```
<configuration>
  <outputDirectory>/some/absolute/path</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

See http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-report-plugin/examples/report-custom-location.html for details.

If you want the report in both places, the most simple solution might be to run the report plugin twice by [creating two executions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-default-execution-ids.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add a plugin with a shell command to copy

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
  <executions>
   <execution>
      <id>copy_report</id>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <executable>/bin/cp</executable>
    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/your/output/dir</workingDirectory>
    <arguments>
       <argument>your_report.txt</argument>
       <argument>/path/to/the/other/location</argument>
    </arguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```